# How can I identify if an OpenSSL connection is successful?

Tags: tls, openssl

I am trying to find out if TLSv1 and TLSv1.2 are disabled, so I am using the following commands:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect servername:port -tls1
openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect servername:port -tls1_1
openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect servername:port -tls1_2
```

I am getting very different outputs. Some of them are generating an error, so I guess the negotiation failed and the connection wasn't established. In other cases, I see some outputs on which the handshake reads 0 bytes and writes 0 bytes, and also it seems to be an error: "write:errno=104". And in other cases, it looks like is connecting with no issues.

However, I am not 100% sure and I need help to identify if the connection were successful. How can I do it? How can I know when a connection has failed or worked?

Some of the outputs I am getting... Please note that I have removed some lines because I am unsure if they include sensible information.

### Case 1

I think this one is failing (**write:errno=104**), but not sure why...

```
[username@node1 ]$ openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect node1:port -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x21b64d0 [0x21cd6d3] (181 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1640871716
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

### Case 2

Same here (**139889728124816:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40**):

```
[username@node2 ]$ openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect node2:port -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x1c534d0 [0x1c6a6d3] (181 bytes => 181 (0xB5))
(I removed some lines)
139889728124816:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40
139889728124816:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1640871912
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

### Case 3

This one is similar to the last one (**error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:365**):

```
[username@node2 ]$ openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect node2:port -tls1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x23084d0 [0x231f6d3] (181 bytes => 181 (0xB5))
(I removed some lines)
139833724217232:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:365:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1640871957
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

### Case 4

Again, this looks similar to the others (**error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 70** and **error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659**):

```
[username@node1 ~]$ openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect node1:port -tls1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x10ee3f0 [0x11055c3] (181 bytes => 181 (0xB5))
(I removed some lines)
140090843924368:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 70
140090843924368:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1640872087
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

### Case 5

Finally, I think this one is working:

```
[username@node1 ~]$ openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect node1:port -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0xff73f0 [0x100e5c3] (289 bytes => 289 (0x121))
(I removed some lines)
depth=0 C = ES, ST = Madrid, L = Madrid, O = CBEC, OU = cbec IT, CN = blabla.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = ES, ST = Madrid, L = Madrid, O = CBEC, OU = cbec IT, CN = blabla.com
verify return:1
read from 0xff73f0 [0x100a073] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
(I removed some lines)
0040 - <SPACES/NULS>
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=ES/ST=Madrid/L=Madrid/O=CBEC/OU=cbec IT/CN=blabla.com
   i:/C=ES/ST=Madrid/L=Madrid/O=CBEC/OU=cbec IT/CN=blabla.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(I removed some lines)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=ES/ST=Madrid/L=Madrid/O=CBEC/OU=cbec IT/CN=blabla.com
issuer=/C=ES/ST=Madrid/L=Madrid/O=CBEC/OU=cbec IT/CN=blabla.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1289 bytes and written 631 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: (I removed the line)
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: (I removed the line)
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86400 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    (I removed the lines)
    Start Time: 1640872114
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

If no cipher was agreed on, then the connection is definitely not successful, i.e. this means a failure

```
Cipher    : 0000
```

Also, if the connection was sufficiently successful then `openssl s_client` is waiting for input (which then gets send to the peer), otherwise it will immediately exit.

Note that `openssl s_client` considers a connection sufficiently successful even if the certificate validation failed (check `Verify return code:` - should be 0 on success) because it is self-signed, expired, issued by an untrusted CA ...

Thus only in your last example the connection was sufficiently successful. It failed though to validate the certificate, i.e. a browser would complain here and tools with strict certificate checking (like most tools today by default) would abort the connection.